# Simple Asp.Net MVC2 Binding question: How to get an EditorFor to render a Radio Button Group?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, radio-button

Just thinking out loud about the subject, If I have the following:

```
 <%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.Gender, "Gender")
```

And I want it to render two radio buttons:

```
 O Male  O Female
```

Assuming the class just has a string to hold the value, what would the Gender.ascx look like if we were to pass the Gender values using something like

```
 ViewData["Gender"] = new string[] {"Male", "Female"};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Radio button example (Yes No):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%= Html.RadioButton("", "Yes") %> Yes
<%= Html.RadioButton("", "No") %> No
```

And another Radio Button set (Gender):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%= Html.RadioButton("", "Male") %> Male
<%= Html.RadioButton("", "Female") %> Female
```

And a Drop Down Menu (Marital Status):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%= Html.DropDownList("", new SelectList(new[] {"N/A",
    "Single", "Married", "Divorced", "Widowed" })) %>
```

Now I need to modify these to look for a matching ViewData[""] list of options or figure out how to pass a selection list to the partial UI Template.

Comment: This doesn't explain using the EditorFor method, though.